# Getting gvim to show unicode

Tags: windows-xp, gvim, unicode

How to get GVim (v. 7.3. on Windows XP, if that matters) to show Unicode characters? Something along the lines of

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/
(search for *listchars* to see the little triangle I'm trying to get).

I'm using

```
set encoding,
set fileencoding,
and set fileencodings,
```

all to utf-8, if that helps.

I know it must be something simple, but nevertheless, here I am, stuck. Help.

Answer (score 6):

After turning on Unicode display in Vim with

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

you may need to reload the file for it to take effect. Do `:e!` to reload the file. If it works, you may want to put `set encoding=utf-8` in your vimrc file.

Answer (score 5):

Is your current font capable of displaying all the characters you're using? If not, then you need to change the font used by GVim. Check out [this thread at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235671/how-do-i-add-a-font-in-gvim-on-windows-system). Excerpt:

> For MS-Windows, some fonts have a limited number of Unicode characters. Try using the "Courier New" font. You can use the Edit/Select Font... menu to select and try out the fonts available. Only fixed-width fonts can be used though. Example:
>
> ```
> :set guifont=courier_new:h12
> ```

Comment: I've tried Cou.New, Courier, Consolas, Lucida Console, ... all I get is a little square box with a question mark.

Comment: @RookL for which characters? (you can press `ga` over a character to find its unicode value. It is possible that the font does not have that character.

Comment: `:set guifontwide=MingLiU:h10`  (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14613767/239408) is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to change encoding with:

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Read the question again.